# Are there any validation techniques for validation techniques?

Tags: validation

I believe the vast number of contemporary scoring systems and scales such as for social anxiety, narcissism, etc, are considered to be a core part of modern psychology research because they are “validated”. However, has anyone put forward the question if these validation techniques are completely reliable? How do we know? Is there a way to validate such a validation technique?